# Identifying binomial distribution for finding variance

Tags: probability, statistics

> If a variable $x$ takes values $0,1,2,....n$ with frequencies equal to the binomial coefficients $\binom {12}0,\binom {12}1,\binom {12}2,.....\binom {12}{12}$, then variance of distribution is

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
x& 0 & 1 & 2&......&12 \\ \hline
f &\binom {12}0 &\binom {12}1 &\binom {12}2&......&\binom {12}{12}\\ \hline
\end{array}

It is solved in my reference as
$$
\sigma^2=n/4=12/4=3
$$
as if it is a binomial distribution with $p=q=1/2$.

I understand it must be a binomial distribution but where do we have the clue that the probability of success in each trial is $1/2$ ?

My thinking says irrespective of the probability of success the frequency of each case is the above binomial coefficients. So where am I thinking wrong about it ?

Comment: If $P(X=x)\propto \binom{12}{x}$ for $x=0,1,\ldots,12$, you can easily find the normalizing constant of the probability distribution.

Comment: @StubbornAtom whan you have a binomial distribution with $n=12$, $P(X=x)=\binom {12}x p^xq^{12-x}$ and the corresponding frequency is $f(X=x)=\binom {12}x$ irrespecive of $p$, right ?

Comment: @StubbornAtom When I think that way we are only given the frequencies not the probability of success, $p$ in each case ?

Comment: The way the question is written after the edit, looks like you ought to calculate variance like you do for a grouped data.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Sorry for that. Actually only the table is given in my reference, and asking to calculate the variance

Comment: @StubbornAtom even with the previous statement it does not sy probability is proportional to the binomial coefficient right ?

Comment: There is no mention of probability in the question. It helps to see this as a binomial distribution with probabilities proportional to the binomial coefficient, but there is no need for that. Consider it as a usual frequency distribution and calculate variance like you do for a grouped data. You will end up with the same answer.

Comment: @StubbornAtom my doubt is, how do you identify it as a binomial distribution with $p=q=1/2$ with the information given in the table ?

Comment: @ss1729 By normalizing, which requires you to know that $\sum_{k=0}^{12} {12 \choose k}=2^{12}$ (which follows from the binomial theorem for $(x+y)^n$ with $x=1,y=1,n=12$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a 'binomial distribution' as stated. You are given an ordinary frequency distribution and you are asked to calculate its variance, i.e. variance of the dataset $\{x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_{12}\}$ where $x_i=i$ is the variable of interest with corresponding frequency $f_i=\binom{12}{i}$, $i=0,1,\ldots,12$. So you can just calculate variance like you do for a grouped data.

But you can think of a certain probability if you consider the relative frequency $$f(x)=\frac{f_x}{\sum_{x=0}^{12}f_x}=\frac1{2^{12}}\binom{12}{x}\,.$$

This as you know is the probability mass function of a binomial distribution with parameter $\left(12,\frac12\right)$ evaluated at $x$ when $x\in\{0,1,\ldots,12\}$. It will be immediate that the required variance is just the variance of this binomial distribution once you write down the expression of variance for grouped data.

Answer (score 0):

Think about coin flips. If a biased coin has probability $p$ of landing heads, and $X$ is a random variable (note that $X$ is binomially distributed by design) equal to the number of heads in $12$ flips, then the probability distribution of $X$ is

$$P(X = k) = \binom{12}{k}p^k(1-p)^{12-k}$$

For each $k$, this is proportional to $\binom{12}{k}$ iff $p=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: But where in the question it is stated the probability is proportional to the binomial coefficient !! It only says the frequency of occurrence is the corresponding binomial coefficients, right ?

Comment: and frequency of occurrence in a binomial distribution is the corresponding binomial coefficients, which are irrespective of the probability of success right ?

Comment: The frequencies are clearly proportional to the binomial coefficients (as opposed to  binomial coefficients scaled by a geometrically varying factor)